# How to load same js file with multiple babel settings via webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

My team owns a custom element loader script who's job is to pull down polyfills from [webcomponentsjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) and then define all our custom elements. Depending on whether the browser supports classes or not, we must load one of 2 different component bundles.

Our current build process is messy and cumbersome. We run webpack 3 separate times:

1. Build the components bundle with very minimal transpilation
2. Build the components bundle again, but transpile away classes (for ie11 support)
3. Read the filesystem to figure out what these bundles are named (the file names include hashes so we don't know what they will be up front), and run webpack a 3rd time, injecting in the bundle names from 1 & 2 using webpack's [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Is there a way to choose which babel setup to use based on a query parameter in the import? I'd like to do something like this:

```
if (supportsClasses) {
  import('./components.js');
else {
  import('./components.js?enableTranspilation');
}
```

It would need to change the babel settings for this file **and everything that it imports**.
If this was possible then I'd be able to build the whole project with a single invocation of webpack (instead of 3 separate ones).